# Как найти подстроку в массиве слов, и собрать обратно в массив

Tags: php

У меня есть определенный массив например имен. Необходимо написать функцию с двумя аргументами. Первый аргумент - это массив имен, а второй аргумент -  это, например, буква "А". Нужно перевести массив в строку и найти те слова, в которых содержится второй аргумент. И обратно собрать из получившихся слов массив.

```
<?php
$array = ["Женя", "Леша", "Никита", "Олег", "Давид"];
$testReplaceString = "а";
$array_string = implode(" | ", $array);

$findString = strpos($array_string, $testReplaceString);
if ($findString === false) {
   echo "Строка '$testReplaceString' не найдена в строке '$array_string'";
} else {
   echo "Строка '$testReplaceString' найдена в строке '$array_string'";
}
```

Но данный код, который я написал, выдает мне, что он нашел это в строке. А мне нужно, чтобы вывел те слова, в которых найден тот или иной символ и собрать это в новый массив. Помогите, пожалуйста. Пыху изучаю только второй день.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, Вам достаточно создать новый отфильтрованный массив. Для этой цели хорошо подходит [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php).
Не совсем понимаю, для чего необходимо переводить в строку... Если в качестве первого аргумента будет строка, тогда придется внутри метода делить ее по сепарату с помощью [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php).

Для PHP 7.4+:

```
$array = ["Женя", "Леша", "Никита", "Олег", "Давид"];
$testReplaceString = "а";

function MyFinder($array, $needle){
   return array_filter($array, fn($v) => strpos($v, $needle) !== FALSE);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(MyFinder($array, $testReplaceString ));

echo '</pre>';
```

Для PHP 5.3+:

```
$array = array("Женя", "Леша", "Никита", "Олег", "Давид");
$testReplaceString = "а";

function MyFinder($array, $needle){
   return array_filter($array, function($v) use($needle){
       return strpos($v, $needle) !== FALSE;
     
   });
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(MyFinder($array, $testReplaceString ));

echo '</pre>';
```

Работающий пример [тут](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89beb1ae3292d53d8252f639a4c5d4c67f5f924e)

Comment: Подскажи, а как мне готовый результат вывести в формате JSON ? Спасибо твой пример работает, как нужно. Забыл уточнить про перевод в JSON

Comment: @Dmtr-Tgn, воспользуйтесь `json_encode()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Про json_encode сейчас читал, просто не пойму, что в работающем примере Вашем мне вставить в encode, чтоб он перевел в json его. Извиняюсь если как то неправильно выражаюсь

Comment: @Dmtr-Tgn достаточно `json_encode(MyFinder($array, $testReplaceString ), 256);`, где 256 - поддержка юникода(русских букв)